# How to zip all txt files recursively in linux using zip?

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I want to `zip` all `.txt` files in using `zip` command in `linux` recursively. For this, I'm using:

```
zip -r /home/folder/zipName /home/folder2/subfolder1/*.txt
```

and it is giving me the below error:

```
zip warning: missing end signature--probably not a zip file (did you
zip warning: remember to use binary mode when you transferred it?)
zip warning: (if you are trying to read a damaged archive try -F)
zip error: Zip file structure invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
zip -r /home/folder/zipName /home/folder2/subfolder1 -i \*.txt
```

it will do what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ...

```
zip -r /home/folder/zipName /home/folder2/subfolder1/**/*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and I found that the solution was to make sure that your `zipName` ends in `.zip`. Putting this here in case it can help somebody else.